# Reference to a "simple" consistency proof

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

Bartoszynski has written a "simplified" account of Shelah's proof of consistency of "Covering of null ideal has countable cofinality" in his [article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910015v1.pdf) in handbook. In a subsequent [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9705213v2.pdf), Shelah also constructed a model of "The null ideal restricted to some non null set is $\omega_1$-saturated". The proof uses iterations of "partial random reals" and makes several references to his countable cofinality paper and I could not follow it starting page 17. Has someone written a simplified account of this proof that maybe does not refer to Shelah's countable cofinality paper?

Answer (score 3):

Shelah and I have a [preprint](http://www.math.huji.ac.il/~akumar/oprni.pdf) that has a generalization of this. The main result is that the null ideal restricted to a non null set of reals could be isomorphic to a large class of sigma ideals - For example it could be isomorphic to the non stationary ideal on $\omega_1$.